# Adding NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to plist Still Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsurl

I have a PHP file on another machine that creates JSON, and wanted to grab it from iOS application.

I tried to use the IP address to connect from the iOS application with NSURL

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.xx.xxx/JSON/JSONtoIOS.php"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
```

Then, I added below code in `info.plist` file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

However, I am still getting a same error message:

> Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

The URL opens fine on a web browser, but having a problem with NSData returning `nil`.

Can anyone help me on this issue?

**EDIT**: Using NSURLSession in (void)viewDidLoad

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.xx.xxx/JSON/JSONtoIOS.php"] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
{
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", json);
}];
[dataTask resume];
```

Comment: So you edited the Info.plist directly, as XML text? You may have messed up the XML somehow.

Comment: I checked both the XML text and the list. It had no issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
```

That's not how you do networking! It's a misuse of `dataWithContentsOfURL` (it's for opening local file URLs), plus it's synchronous so even if you were networking, you'd be doing a bad thing.

Use NSURLSession to retrieve the data through a data task. Now your NSAppTransportSecurity settings will be obeyed (plus you'll have much better info about what's going on as the networking proceeds).

Comment: Thank you. I have tried using NSURLSession, but still getting the same error. It also says that the reason is because the data parameter is nil: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'

Comment: Not sure if I am using the NSURLSession correctly. I have edited my question.

Comment: That's certainly not how I would do it. For one thing, the session needs to persist; you're making yours a local variable, which vanishes in a puff of smoke before the networking can even get started. For another, you're not doing any error-checking anywhere along the way. You're just jumping off a cliff with your eyes closed, ignoring the nice elevator that awaits you.

Comment: I am pretty new to iOS development, and never used NSURLSession before. It will be great if you can help me out. So I am assuming that I will have to create a strong @property for NSURLSession. Also, I have used NSError and it displays the same error message.

Comment: Using dataWithContentsOfURL isn't generally a good idea, because as you said, it is synchronous.  However, on a non-main thread, I'm pretty sure it is legal, if a bit gross.  :-)

Comment: I used NSURLSession, tested it with iTunes URL, and it worked. I will have to do some more research and connect it with my php file. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

First, it should be Info.plist.  The filesystem is case-sensitive on iOS.  Just to pick nits—I doubt this is your problem.  :-)

Second, make sure you added this in the right place in the Info.plist.  It must be at the top level.

Third, if this app contains any app extensions, frameworks, or anything else that might contain an Info.plist file, make sure you're editing the right Info.plist file.

Fourth, make sure you rebuilt your app afterwards, and that you're really running the rebuilt copy.

Fifth, if that doesn't help, enable CFNetwork diagnostic logging, as described in [QA1887](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1887/_index.html).

Comment: well... I am pretty sure that I am adding it to the right info.plist file. I tried to set it up at the top level but it is not working still. Also, I don't think it is the network issue, it works well on the web browser.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the network issue".  CFNetwork is the software that performs all the URL fetching.  By enabling debugging, you might get more information about why ATS is ignoring what you put in the Info.plist file.  Either way, the problem is with the Info.plist file in some way.  I can't tell precisely what you did wrong, but that's where the problem is.  Well, that and using NSData to fetch non-file URLs is usually a bad idea, as others have mentioned, but you're fixing that already.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
NSData *postData = [someStringToPost dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:someURLString];
```

I think thats where the problem is.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Isn't the NSData supposed to use the URL with dataWithContentsOfURL?